# Chevalley basis for $G_2$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

I want to find the Chevalley basis for the exceptional group $G_2$. 
Could you point to literature where the computation is done in detail or show me how to do it?

Comment: One can find such a basis in Humphreys' *Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation*, $\S$19.3, though he leaves (straightforward) computations to the reader.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome. I promoted my comment to an answer, since it essentially is one.

Answer (score 1):

One can find such a basis in Humphreys' *Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation*, $\S$19.3. He leaves (straightforward) computations to the reader.